# livequery for detecting dom changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

How do I detect the changes in DOM like innerHTML updated etc using JQuery's livequery.

I tried like below

Script -

```
var matched = function() {
        alert('detected');
};
var unmatched = function() {
    alert('removed')
};

$('div#container').livequery(matched, unmatched)
```

HTML -

```
<BODY onload="setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = 'updated test';    },3000);">

  <div id="container">test</div>
 </BODY>
```

But this doesn't work.

Thanks,
Sourabh

Comment: Is there any script error? Have you included all the js files.

Comment: Looks to me like you've told `livequery` to call your functions when an element with `id="container"` is itself added or removed from the DOM. I don't think you're meant to call it when that element's `innerHTML` is changed.

Comment: No actually I am expecting an alert after 3 seconds(science innerHTML is updated), but not getting.although I am getting an alert on page load.

Comment: Ok Crescent, Now I tried using * instead of div#container as a selector but for innerHTML update its not getting triggered.so the problem is resolved for elements added like div,span,option etc. but how do I take care of innerHTML, or option value etc ?

Comment: check my answer. and reread the livequery plugin documentation

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do **is not what the livequery-plugin is designed to do**.

```
$('div#container').livequery(matched, unmatched);
```

This tells livequery to:

- call the matched function when a `div` with id `container` is found or added to the DOM with one of the jQuery DOM-manipulation methods
- call the unmatched function when a `div` with id `container` previously found was removed (or `id` changed) from the DOM with one of the jQuery DOM-manipulation methods

So with your sample it will only fire an alert saying *detected* on page load. As the innerHTML change doesn't neither add nor remove a div with id container livequery is supposed to do nothing and that is what it does.

---

Using `*` (instead of `div#container`) will only fire a couple of alerts on page load but again won't fire as long as you use non jQuery DOM-Manipulation methods.

```
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = 'updated test';
```

Doesn't fire `matched()` as #1 you don't use jQuery to do the manipulation; #2 you don't add a new element which `*` would match.

```
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = '<p>updated test</p>'
```

Doesn't fire `matched()` as you don't use jQuery to do the manipulation (although you add a element `<p>` which would be matched by the `*` selector but isn't registered by livequery as it only listens for jQuery DOM-manipulation methods (and only a selection of them too).

If instead you use

```
$("#container").html('<p>updated test</p>');
```

It will fire `matched()` after 3s. If you only do

```
$("#container").html('updated test');
```

`matched()` won't be fired as nothing was added that would be matched by the `*` selector only the innerHTML of an already matched element was changed